# Days between two dates - typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to calculate the difference in days between two dates.

In the end I need to know if a certain date has expired.

But I can't come up with a solution.

the expiredAt field, is of type datetime

**Service.ts**

```
import CheckLicenses from "../../helpers/CheckLicenses";
await CheckLicenses("valor");
```

**CheckLicenses.ts**

```
import License from "../models/License";
import AppError from "../errors/AppError";
import { logger } from "../utils/logger";

const CheckLicenses = async (company: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    const license = await License.findOne({
        where: { company }
    });

    if (!license) {
        throw new AppError("ERR_NO_LICENCE_FOUND", 404);
    } else {
        const { expiredAt } = license;
        const today = new Date();

        if (expiredAt <= today) throw new AppError("EXPIRED", 401);
    }
    return true;
};

export default CheckLicenses;
```

Comment: What is type of expiredAt ? Timestamp Number or Date

Comment: the type is datetime

Comment: Wooo, new type. Let’s  try `if (expiredAt.valueOf() <= today.valueOf())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are comparing a string type with a date type. If you convert "expiredAt" to date then it will work

```
if (new Date(expiredAt) <= today) throw new AppError("EXPIRED", 401);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As *@Athul Joy* suggested you should use Moment.js.

First install moment from npm using `npm i moment`.

Import moment:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

At your else condition:

```
const expiredMoment = moment(expiredAt); //Cast as moment date
const currentMoment = moment(); //current moment date
if (currentMoment.diff(expiredMoment, 'days') > 0) throw new AppError("EXPIRED", 401);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about trying Moment.js (https://momentjs.com/). Momen.js provides predefined functions to compare dates